# Using \newcommand, \input and \includegraphics

Tags: macros, input

I am writing a paper that includes simulation results from performing a number of trials of an experiment.  Each of the output figures (.pdfs) I produce includes the number of trials in the filename (e.g. `foo_10_trials.pdf`, `foo_100_trials.pdf`, `bar_10_trials.pdf`, `bar_100_trials.pdf`) where the number itself is based off a variable set in a Bash script which is writing the files.  Because the experiments take a while to run, it's convenient to use the low number of trials figures while I'm writing the paper and then include a greater number of trial figures in the final paper.  The issue is I then need to go through and update the number of trials e.g. change all `10`s --> `100`s.

What I'm trying to do is have a file `vars/trials.tex` that simply includes an integer I can change e.g. `100`.  Then in my main manuscript I have `\newcommand{\trials}{\input{vars/trials}}`.  I can use this in-text fine, but what I'd like to be able to do is define my figures in such a way that they use this variable too, e.g.

```
\newcommand{\fooFigure}[0]{
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{foo_\trials{}_trials}
    \caption{Foo caption.}
    \label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}
}

\fooFigure
```

This way, I can update all the figures and all the in-text references by simply changing the `trials.tex` file to e.g. read `100` instead of `10`.  The problem I'm running into with `\includegraphics` is it doesn't seem to accept `\trials{}` as I have it above.  The error I'm getting is:

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
\filename@simple ...#2\\}\fi \edef \filename@base 
                                                  {#1}
l.645 \fooFigure

--- HELP ---
TeX encountered an unknown command name. You probably misspelled the
name. If this message occurs when a LaTeX command is being processed,
the command is probably in the wrong place---for example, the error
can be produced by an \item command that's not inside a list-making
environment. The error can also be caused by a missing \documentclass
command.
```

I'm by no means an expert in TeX/LaTeX, so I don't know if it's an issue of the `\trials` or `\input{vars/trials}` not being expanded for example or something else.

Comment: It should be either `\newcommand{\fooFigure}{...` or `\newcommand{\fooFigure}[1]{...\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{foo_/trials{}_#1}....`

Comment: That is, you never create a newcommand that takes 'zero' arguments by telling it to take '0' arguments: only when there is one or more arguments do you add something like `[1]` or `[2]` and so on.

Comment: I think \trials is suppose to be a macro, in which case one also needs a \newcommand{\trials}{100} or \def\trials{100}.  One can also use {\trials} to insert a macro into the middle of string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Getting the number of trials

From the TeX side it is easier, if the bash script could write a complete
definition in `var/trials.tex`, e.g.

```
\renewcommand*{\trials}{100}
```

Then the file can be easily read by TeX:

```
\providecommand*{\trial}{10}% default setting
\input{var/trials}
```

If the file `var/trials.tex` only contains an integer, then it can be read
via package `catchfile`:

```
\usepackage{catchfile}
\CatchFileEdef{\trials}{var/trials.tex}{\endlinechar=-1 }
```

The last command removes the line ends of `var/trials.tex` to avoid additional
white space after the number.

### Using `\trials`

Macro `\trials` as defined above does not have arguments. An additional pair of braces are therefore *not* removed and would become part of the file name. A space suffices to end macro `\trials` and the space will not be part of the file name (e.g. `foo\trials bar` would become `foo100bar`). But since a period is following, also the space is not necessary:

```
\includegraphics[...]{foo_\trials.pdf}
```